# Python script can't find module

Tags: python-3.x, module, raspberry-pi, importerror, wiringpi

I am new to the world of programming,
I want to use this piece of code to move a little servo:

```
# Servo Control
# Servo Control
import time
import wiringpi

# use 'GPIO naming'
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()

# set #18 to be a PWM output
wiringpi.pinMode(18, wiringpi.GPIO.PWM_OUTPUT)

# set the PWM mode to milliseconds stype
wiringpi.pwmSetMode(wiringpi.GPIO.PWM_MODE_MS)

# divide down clock
wiringpi.pwmSetClock(192)
wiringpi.pwmSetRange(2000)

delay_period = 0.01

while True:
        for pulse in range(50, 250, 1):
                wiringpi.pwmWrite(18, pulse)
                time.sleep(delay_period)
        for pulse in range(250, 50, -1):
                wiringpi.pwmWrite(18, pulse)
                time.sleep(delay_period)
```

When i run this piece of code in the idle i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/servo.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wiringpi
ImportError: No module named 'wiringpi'
```

I did install wiringpi. 
and i checked for it using:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

I found it between:

```
wireless-regdb
wireless-tools
wiringpi
wolfram-engine
wolframscript
```

Please help with what you can thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change to *sudo pip3 install wiringpi*. Thats happen because the python interpreter is V2.7

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal, then

type this:

```
sudo apt-get python-dev python-pip
```

then this:

```
sudo pip install wiringpi
```

or if the 2nd line of code doesn't work then type this:

```
sudo pip install wiringpi2
```

if you install wiringpi2, instead of "import wiringpi", you must type "import wiringpi2"

This solved my issue! Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately i am still getting the same error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PLZ.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wiringpi
ImportError: No module named 'wiringpi'

Comment: Then, you must use import wiringpi2 (after you install it).

Comment: I kept getting the same error for both wiringpi and wiringpi2. I am now using RPI.GPIO. It works for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I believe wiring pi wont work with higher versions of python.  Wiringpi 2 is supporting versions higher than 2.7 but wont work with 3.4.  Depending of your version you have a few options:

1. Use python 2.7
2. Use an alternative like rpio

https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/